# Wiremock XML request matching with XPath contains or RegEx

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xunit, wiremock

Need to implement a matching condition with **XPath** (*or with RegEx*) text contains and multiple **OR** values.

My request body:

```
<person_obj>
    <params>
        <name>David J</name>
        <loca>NY</loca>
    </params>
</person_obj>
```

Matching Conditions:
`name` tag contains with `David` or `Jack` or `Mike` and other elements/tags can be ignored.

i.e., which I've tried

```
"bodyPatterns": [
    {
      "ignoreArrayOrder" : true,
      "ignoreExtraElements" : true,
      "matchesXPath":{
        "expression": "//person_obj/params/name/text()",
        "or": [
          {"contains": "David"}, {"contains": "Mike"}, {"contains": "Jack"}
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems working.

```
"bodyPatterns": [
    {
      "matchesXPath":{
        "expression": "/person_obj/params/name/text()",
        "or": [
          {"contains": "David"}, {"contains": "Mike"}, {"contains": "Jack"}
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for separate or-property. Just use an XPath predicate on text().

```
expression": "//person_obj/params/name/text()[contains(.,'David' or .,'Mike' or .,'Jack')]"
```